# How to update google_bigquery_table_iam_member to point to new table on recreation due to an updated schema

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a BigQuery table and an add a service account as an iam member to this table:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
  dataset_id          = dataset
  table_id            = table
  project             = project
  schema              = "jsonSchema.json"
}

resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access_right" {
  project    = google_bigquery_table.table.project
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_table.table.dataset_id
  table_id   = google_bigquery_table.table.table_id
  role       = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
  member     = "serviceAccount:serviceAccount@GCPserviceAccount.com"
}
```

Removing a column from `jsonSchema.json`  and applying the changes enforces the destruction of the table and the creation of a new one:

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.module.google_bigquery_table.table must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
      ...
      ~ schema              = jsonencode(
          ~ [ # forces replacement
                # (8 unchanged elements hidden)
                {
                    mode = "REQUIRED"
                    name = "column1"
                    type = "TIMESTAMP"
                },
              - {
                  - mode = "REQUIRED"
                  - name = "column2"
                  - type = "STRING"
                },
            ]
        )
      ...

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

At this point the `google_bigquery_table_iam_member` resource created is still pointing to the old table in the state. However, in GCP the service account no longer has access to the non existing table and no new access has been given to the newly created table.

Running `terraform apply` a second time it notices the missing access

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # module.module.google_bigquery_table_iam_member.access_rights will be created
  + resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access_rights" {
      + dataset_id = "dataset"
      + etag       = (known after apply)
      + id         = (known after apply)
      + member     = "serviceAccount:serviceAccount@GCPserviceAccount.com"
      + project    = "project"
      + role       = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
      + table_id   = "table"
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
```

Is it possible to achieve this in a single step (a single terraform apply)?
i.e.

- The `table` gets destroyed and recreated.
- The `access_right` resource updates so the SA has access to the new table.

Comment: I want to clarify something. You want to add IAM permission to one of the BigQuery tables for SA? Have you created a new ServiceAccount with proper permission using Terraform or manually? From your snipet I can see that you are creating a new Table and want to give permission to this table only for 1 SA? Could you clarify what exactly you want to achieve in one step?

Comment: @PjoterS
The SA is created with terraform (not shown in the question). The permissions are created in TF (the access_right resource in the first code snippet).

The initial config already has the table created. When I update the BQ schema, it forces a recreation of the BA table. 

What I want to achieve in one step (single terraform apply) is: 
* The table gets destroyed and recreated. 
* The access_right resource updates so the SA has access to the new table.

Comment: I tried to replicate this behavior and run a few tests. It works for me as expected when Table was created via Terraform script and then I've updated script with `ServiceAccount` and `google_bigquery_table_iam_member`. Does this table was created via Terraform script, then you edit schema and run updated script with new Service account and binding? What Terraform version are you using? There is also an option that binding action was performed before new table was created thus binding was to old table not new.

Comment: In this situation you could use [sleep](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/sleep) resource. I will try different test tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: @PjoterS Thank you! 
This was run using terraform 1.1.3 and google provider version 4.5.0, updating to 1.1.4 and 4.9.0 eliminated the problem.
Can I ask for advice, do I delete the question or answer it?

Comment: I think you should keep this question and you can provide answer for it and mar as accepted. Someone might have very similar issue and that solution might also work for another user. Im still doing some testing and later I will provide answer with those test. Someday it might help someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running this setup with:

```
terraform version 1.1.4
google provider version 4.9.0
```

Rather than:

```
terraform version 1.1.3
google provider version 4.5.0
```

eliminated the issue.

However, if you for some reason cannot do that, @PjoterS has an [alternative solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70987317/2758758)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment section by OP, the solution was to upgrade [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/downloads) and the `provider` versions. However as I performed a few tests I wanted to share output of them.

Another option to solve this issue is to use [recreate](https://www.terraform.io/cli/state/taint). Below Example how it works.

**main.tf**

```
### Creating Service Account
resource "google_service_account" "bigquerytest" {
  project      = "<MyProjectID>"
  account_id   = "bigquery-table"
  display_name = "bigquery-table-test"
  provider     = google
}
### Re-Create table
resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
  dataset_id = "test"
  table_id = "bqtable"
  project = "<MyProjectID>"
  schema  = file("/home/<myuser>/terrabq/jsonSchema.json")
  deletion_protection=false
}

### DataEditor binding
resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access-right" {
  project = "<MyProjectID>"
  dataset_id = "<YourDataset_id>"
  table_id = "bqtable"
  role = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
  member = "serviceAccount:${google_service_account.bigquerytest.email}"
}
```

**jsonSchema.json**

```
[
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "source",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
    "mode": "NULLABLE",
    "name": "status",
    "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "test",
  "type": "STRING"
  },
  {
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "test4",
  "type": "STRING"
  }
]
```

**Scenario:**
Create a new `Table - bqtable` with specific schema, create `ServiceAccount` and proper `IAM member` permission for this `Table`.

**Output:**

```
...
Plan: 3 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
...
google_service_account.bigquerytest: Creating...
google_bigquery_table.table: Creating...
google_bigquery_table.table: Creation complete after 1s [id=projects/<myproject>/datasets/test/tables/bqtable]
google_service_account.bigquerytest: Creation complete after 1s [id=projects/<myproject>/serviceAccounts/bigquery-table@<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
google_bigquery_table_iam_member.access-right: Creating...
google_bigquery_table_iam_member.access-right: Creation complete after 4s [id=projects/<myproject>/datasets/test/tables/bqtable/roles/bigquery.dataEditor/serviceAccount:bigquery-table@<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
```

Next step is to change the schema in `jsonSchema.json`.

### NOTE

- When you are adding column in the schema, the table won't be recreated. It will just update the table and in all new column will be `NULL` value.

```
 # google_bigquery_table.table will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
```

In BQ it would looks like that:

[image]

- When you are removing column from schema

```
  # google_bigquery_table.table must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
```

**Please keep in mind that if the `Table` will be recreated, all data from it will be purged.**

#### Issued scenario:

If you will just change the schema (remove column), the table will be recreated but IAM rules weren't updated.

Plan output was probably like that: `Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy`.

OP was able to solve this issue with an updated version of `Terraform` and `provider`.

However, if you still have issues, you can use `-replace` flag to re-create resource.

```
$ terraform apply -replace=google_bigquery_table_iam_member.access-right
```

Actions taken by terraform was:

```
  # google_bigquery_table.table must be replaced
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_table" "table" {
...
  # google_bigquery_table_iam_member.access-right will be replaced, as requested
-/+ resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access-right" {
      ~ etag       = "<randomString>" -> (known after apply)
      ~ id         = "projects/<myproject>/datasets/<mydataset>/tables/bqtable/roles/bigquery.dataEditor/serviceAccount:bigquery-table@<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com" -> (known after apply)
      ~ table_id   = "projects/<myproject>/datasets/<mydataset>/tables/bqtable" -> "bqtable"
        # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }

Plan: 2 to add, 0 to change, 2 to destroy.
```

In Addition to `depends_on` in terraform, it's used mainly for ordering or to postpone creation of resources.

**To sum up:**

- Solution which worked for OP was updating Terraform and Provider versions
- Another solution is to use `terraform apply -replace=[resource.resourcename]`

Answer (score 0):

This is weird behavior maybe caused by the provider knowing the result of the resource fields beforehand and confusing terraforms implicit dependency detection.

You can try to force the dependency by adding an explicit `depends_on` to the iam resource to ensure recreation:

```
resource "google_bigquery_table_iam_member" "access_right" {
  project    = google_bigquery_table.table.project
  dataset_id = google_bigquery_table.table.dataset_id
  table_id   = google_bigquery_table.table.table_id
  role       = "roles/bigquery.dataEditor"
  member     = "serviceAccount:serviceAccount@GCPserviceAccount.com"

  depends_on = [google_bigquery_table.table]
}
```

in this case terraform should be able to detect changes as you now also depend on changing fields like `etag` that are only known after apply.

To better understand the issue a plan output of an initial apply would help.

Comment: I actually tried the depends_on parameter without success. However, this seems to be resolved by updating terraform and google provider version